# Why can you not "OR Throw" in line?

Tags: javascript

This seems fairly silly, but I don't understand why this is syntactically incorrect

`const foo = a || throw "cannot be undefined"`

when this is fine

```
  const b = () => throw 'cannot be undefined'
  const foo  a || b()
```

Comment: Because `b` in the second case works as a function while your first case doesnt.

Comment: Voted to close this because any answer different from "<del>Simon</del> ECMAScript says throw is a statement, not an expression" is opinion-based. BTW, there's already [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) for changing this.

Comment: Where is 2nd fine? My Chrome says "Unexpected token throw" in the bottom case. Are you confusing it with `const b = () => { throw new 'cannot be undefined' }` (with braces)?

Comment: `throw "cannot be undefined"` think of it like a special function that doesn't return anything just prints something and block stuff, normally the expression `var foo = a || b` will assign to foo a if it's not null or b if a is null,say a is null and b is the throw statement, what assignment do you expect to happen ? so the compiler doesn't take the risk of having a 50/50 chance of blowing up, on the other hand when it is a function if a is null it execute this function, because it is a defined function not a special one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`throw` is a statement.

`b()` is an expression.

`a || b` takes two expressions, and produces an expression.

Every expression can be a statement. The converse does not hold.

Note that this is also not grammatical (contrary to what you claim):

```
const b = () => throw new 'cannot be undefined'
```

but this is:

```
const b = () => { throw new 'cannot be undefined' }
```

because the arrow function has two forms:

- `params => expression` or
- `params => { statement* }`

Comment: Do note that there is [a proposal that adds syntax to allow `throw` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) (stage 2 and ready for stage 3 I believe) which would work in both expression contexts discussed here.

Comment: @Li357 Indeed - raina77ow already had it noted under question comments, and I didn't think I need to steal it into the answer :) Not yet though. Not yet.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice